# Why YouTube copyright disputes do not include the "company is claiming content it does not own" option?

Tags: youtube, copyright

It has now happened to me many times that the **ContentID system wrongly assign copyright claims to the wrong companies**:

songs of little known artists claimed by big majors, little known foreign companies claiming old national hits as totally different tracks and *so on down the ladder*.

My biggest problem when this happens is that there is no option to report that; also if you try not giving money to the wrong author (or *copyright troll*) through the available dispute options, you could get easily getting banned whenever the original author gets his claim done right, basically because the form forced you to lie:

[image: No wrong claim]

So at the present moment if you get a copyright claim by a wrong author you are stuck giving him money and you can't do anything about it without risking your account getting banned.

**Why is that? Why is there is no "invalid claim" option? Why do YouTube and Google indulge in this ambiguous behaviour?**